# JSON Deserialization of a matrix of values using VB.net and Newtonsoft

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net

I have a large set of data (several measurements at a number of time points) but for simplicity sake the JSON string looks like this: {"Data":[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]}. I want to translate these values into an array (data(2,2) as integer).

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
Public Class Form1
    Dim JSON_string As String = "{""Data"":[[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]}"
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of List(Of Integer)))(JSON_string)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm stuck!

Comment: You can use a `Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Integer()))`

Comment: You were not considering the `Data` portion of the json. Which the comment above solves.